# Error importing a previously exported mysql trigger

Tags: mysql, triggers

I had a mysql trigger that has been working, I exported it and removed it and am trying to put it back, but I keep running into the following error:

```
#1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '' at line 12
```

My trigger is:

```
    CREATE TRIGGER `accounts_tracking` AFTER UPDATE ON `accounts`
 FOR EACH ROW BEGIN
IF( NEW.`check_level` != OLD.`check_level` ) THEN
INSERT INTO `accounts_tracking` ( `change_type`, `account_id`, `field`, `old_int`, `new_int`, `old_time`, `new_time` )
VALUES
( "1", 
 OLD.id, 
 "check_level",
 OLD.`check_level`, 
 NEW.`check_level`, 
 UNIX_TIMESTAMP(), 
 UNIX_TIMESTAMP());
END IF;
END
```

Line #12 is the 2nd UNIX_TIMESTAMP()

My table structure is as follows:

```
CREATE TABLE `accounts_tracking` (
  `id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `change_type` smallint(5) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `account_id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `field` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `old_int` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `new_int` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `new_time` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `old_time` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  KEY `account_id` (`account_id`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM  DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;
```

Server type: MySQL
Server version: 5.1.73-log

Thanks.

Comment: Maybe a dumb question, but have you enclosed your trigger between `delimiter $$` (for example) and `delimter ;`?

Comment: @BK435 Just trying to remove the obvious... I see you've posted it as an answer

Comment: @BK435 It remains to know if it solves the OP issue ;)

Comment: Yes it was, not sure what I was thinking... oh well, thanks :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As barranka suggested in comments section, you need to enclose this trigger in a delimiter, like so:

```
DELIMITER $$
    CREATE TRIGGER `accounts_tracking` AFTER UPDATE ON `accounts`
 FOR EACH ROW BEGIN
IF( NEW.`check_level` != OLD.`check_level`) THEN
INSERT INTO `accounts_tracking` ( `change_type`, `account_id`, `field`, `old_int`, `new_int`, `old_time`, `new_time` )
VALUES
( "1", 
 OLD.id, 
 "check_level",
 OLD.`check_level`, 
 NEW.`check_level`, 
 UNIX_TIMESTAMP(), 
 UNIX_TIMESTAMP());
END IF;
END$$
DELIMITER ;
```

The reason is that by adding a [Begin and End](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/trigger-syntax.html) to the statement you are essentially creating a [stored routine/procedure](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/stored-programs-defining.html) with the trigger itself.  In order to run multiple statements, like in stored routine/procedure, you need to add delimiters.

In other cases where you do not have the Begin and End within the trigger, you do not need the delimiters. For Example:

```
CREATE TABLE account (acct_num INT, amount DECIMAL(10,2));
CREATE TRIGGER ins_sum BEFORE INSERT ON account FOR EACH ROW SET @sum = @sum + NEW.amount;
```

Comment: Thanks, can't believe I missed that.